# Oracle PL-SQL: insert a rowtype after select - no enough values

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, insert, rowtype

Im trying to execute a block in PL/SQL that

- Get the actual data of a row by doing table%rowtype
- Modify an attribute from it
- And then inserting the record in a INSERT INTO...VALUES statement like follows.

```
    declare
       v_record table%ROWTYPE
    begin
         select *
         into v_record
         from X_table;

         insert into X_table values (v_record)
     end;
```

But the error that raises when I do this is **PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values**

Answer (score 4):

I've solved this issue removing the parenthesis from the values selection in the INSERT statement.

For example:

```
    insert into X_table values v_record;
```